# How to send the data by using click method to another html file while executing the function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to send content of section tag from First file to second file using jQuery method and function which execution is inside of that method, the definition of that function is in seperate file as it shown below. I got Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of null - I don't know where is my mistake.

first HTML

```js
cart = [];
class Item {
    constructor(name, price, count){
        this.name = name;
        this.price = price;
        this.count = count;
    };
} 
addItemToCart = function(name,price,count){
    for (let i in cart) {
        if ((cart[i]).name === name){
            (cart[i]).count += count;
            return;
        }
    }
    let item = new Item(name,price,count);
    (cart).push(item);
    $("#show-cart").html(cart)
}
saveCart = function(){
    localStorage.setItem("cart",JSON.stringify(cart));
}
loadCart = function(){
    cart = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("cart")); 
}
loadCart();
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="shopcart.css"> 
    </head>
    <body>
        <section class="a" id="title">Relax in the morning</section>
        <section class="a" id="price">100$</section>
        <form id="form1" runat="server">
            <div>
                <input type="button" id="btnClick" value="Submit" onclick="addItemToCart(title,price,1);" />
            </div>
        </form>
        <script>

            $("section").click(function(event){
                event.preventDefault();

                const name = $(this).attr("#title");
                const price = Number($(this).attr("#price"));

                localStorage.setItem("title",JSON.stringify(name));
                localStorage.setItem("price", JSON.stringify(price));
                
                addItemToCart(name,price,1);


            });

        </script>
        <script src="main.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title> Shopping Cart</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="shopcart.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <main>
            <div id="show-cart"></div>


        </main>

        <footer>
        </footer>

        <script src="main.js">
            const title = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("title"));
            const price = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("price"));
        </script>

    </body>    
</html>
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "localSession". It would be helpful if you show the code where you try using it. Do you mean [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API/Using_the_Web_Storage_API)? Also, you are getting error messages in your webpage console output, try fixing those first. But from how I understand your question, using localStorage is one way to do what you need.

Comment: I was thinking about localStorage and I repaired these errors. After simplyfing the code I still get error which I don't understand. I will edit my post and show how my code looks now.

Comment: Maybe try cart.push vs (cart).push

Comment: i tried, without change